# EntityFramework.Extensions simple .Delete() throws null reference exception

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-extended

So I'm trying something like the following with EntityFramework.Extended:

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

```
context.Logs.Delete(l => l.Id == 216471);
```

*This is the simplest example I can provide.*

The problem is this and any other .Delete() I try to do is giving me a:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm using EF 5.0.0 and EF.Extended 5.0.0.73 against an Oracle 11gR2 database.

Any ideas? :)

Cross post on GitHub: http://bit.ly/12Z6xj2

Comment: `context.Logs` is probably null for some reason. I'm not familiar with EF.Extended, but you may want to look into the context and see if there's some reason it's not being populated with some sort of `DbSet`.

Comment: var count = context.Logs.Count(); returns 12731 and select count(*) from log; returns 12731 so I'm sure it's not NULL... And I can enumerate the results set in Visual Studio... etc etc

Comment: Just a guess... there is no log with Id == 216471...

Comment: select * from log where ID = 216471; returns a result, so nope! :D

Comment: Did you try the select from EF or some "management studio"?

Comment: Full stacktrace on the Exception? I suspect that the reason is that you are using Oracle as opposed to SQL Server or SQL Server CE.

Comment: The exception is as shown above, there is no InnerException... But I suspect that it's definitely Oracle-related (isn't every problem?).

Answer (score 0):

try context.Logs.where(l => l.Id == 216471).Delete()

Comment: Still seeing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"... :(

Comment: did you set a breakpoint on this statement,or could you see which objec is null ? make sure EF.Extended is lastest version

Comment: it seems that the Extended batch methods don't support oracle :(

Comment: since you have re-wrote it, maybe you should show the code, otherwise noboby knows if he can give you a help.  :)

Comment: DELETE FROM LOG WHERE CREATEDDATE < to_timestamp('01-07-2013 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'); i.e. this has nothing to do with my question...

Comment: sorry, I thought you re-wrote the batch method :(